# SQL How to put all columns in one column and all cells in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use SQL to create a table with a reduced number of columns and an increased number of rows, from a table with many columns, by putting all columns in one column and all cells in another column.

My table:

| Person | Hobbies | School | Jobs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Tennis | University | Doctor |
| Dave | Chess | Highschool | Chef |
| Tim | Travel | University | Sales |

Desired output:

| Person | Column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Hobbies | Tennis |
| Mark | School | University |
| Mark | Jobs | Doctor |
| Dave | Hobbies | Chess |
| Dave | School | Highschool |
| Dave | Jobs | Chef |
| Tim | Hobbies | Travel |
| Tim | School | University |
| Tim | Jobs | Sales |

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this similar question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You may need to select each field value separately, then apply a `UNION ALL` on the three obtained sets of records.

```
SELECT Person, 'Hobbies' AS Column_, Hobbies AS Value_ FROM tab
UNION ALL
SELECT Person, 'School' AS Column_, School AS Value_ FROM tab
UNION ALL
SELECT Person, 'Jobs' AS Column_, Jobs AS Value_ FROM tab
ORDER BY Person
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szuYhkRwoHujo2zRSgzmmq/0).